# java: cpu 100% of usage. what optimization tricks can be done?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, cpu

My java program takes 30-70% of CPU usage and 3% of Memory (I use TOP linux function).
I run a 32bits version of java.

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Is there a way to make it faster ? Some optimization to un the java software ? (I don't have the source code, so no source code optimization is possible).

Installing a 64bits of java would help ? some other optimization tricks ?

Comment: you are to vague about what your program does. Optimization need understanding...

Comment: do you have some while loops without sleeps in threads? or just infinite loops?

Comment: @Sergey Benner: He said he doesn't have the source code.

Comment: You can probably find out a root cause by running a profiler say (jvisualvm profiler) and monitor it. But the application needs understanding what it does first of all it might only occupy a CPU at a startup time while doing some indexing of some sort. If profiler finds out it's a bug then I'm afraid there's no chance of improving. Anyways you have to understand what it does first of all then doing assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell based on your description, but here are few tips:

1. Add:

   ```
   -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
   ```

   JVM options. Frequently running GC may cause excessive CPU usage.
2. Using `top` and `jstack` you can easily discover which Java threads are consuming most of the CPU.
3. Finally plug in some Java profiler (they don't require sources) and examine results.

However wants you discover which threads/methods (stack traces and profiling will help you) consume the CPU, you cannot do anything more without the source code and ability to tweak it.

Answer (score 2):

64bit java will definitely increase the memory usage, but you have no guarantee of lowering CPU usage. Your best bet is to contact the software vendor and send them your specs saying what's the problem. In the meantime you can invest in better hardware.

Optimizing CPU usage without being able to interfere with the source code is a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

As Jörg mentioned in his comment: "Optimization need understanding." On the current level of understanding (i.e. no source code, no plain description of the purpose of the program), your choices are down to:

- Check the JVM memory settings (perhaps the Java GC is the culprit)
- Use another, better program,
- Buy better hardware

Answer (score 0):

Given  that you do not have source code with you and your normal run takes at max 70% CPU, there is no way to make your program consume 100% CPU. Unless your program depends on some external complex input that you can tweak.

But it seems you goal is running your program faster, which is not possible if it was written badly or without optimisation in mind.

Again, a better CPU may run it faster but that is not "running as optimal".

The fact that it consumes only **3% memory** and **30-70% CPU** indicates that the **program is slow** in whatever it does. Since it is not consuming too much memory and too much CPU, it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have too much choice, if you don't have the source and the CPU is heavily required, then the code is certainly the problem here.

For performance test, you could try other JRE like openjdk. But don't think you'll gain a lot. The best you can do is to by a new faster CPU.